# Editing only a partial model in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm quite new to MVC, and stumbled on a problem. I've googled a lot but couldn't find a solution.

I'm using ASP.Net Membership with roles.

Lets say I have a model of a product with attributes:

- Name
- Art no
- Category

How can I implement this so different roles cab only be allowed to edit parts of the object?
(Let's say one role cannot change the category of a product, for example.)

Is it possible to have different Views for the same Model or different Models for the same object?

If I leave out some of the properties, they will have NULL value when I save them.
I tried using `@HTML.HiddenFor(...)` but then the validation for those fields failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ViewModel sounds like it would do the trick. For all but the most trivial of scenarios, you will get into problems when you tightly couple the Model and the View.

If you havent used them before, a ViewModel is simply a class (model) for the specific view you are rendering. You can customize required properties and validation on the ViewModel and then bind it to the Model, so the structure is most more flexible and easy to work with.

There is a detailed intro at ViewModels http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/asp-dot-net-mvc-viewmodel-usage-and-pick-your-best-pattern

EDIT

You could then have a ViewModel for each of the role, although if you are only looking to protect a property from being updated by certain roles there should be other solutions such as setting the html input to disabled and then testing on the server that the category value is still in its original state (note you should always perform such a test as the Post request can be altered).

Comment: I was going to say the same thanks for Judo. You should have two different ViewModels.

Comment: Thanks. I finally got this working.
I use AutoMapper to convert from Model to the ViewModel.

Still having one issue though.
Let's say that in one of the ViewModels i have no "Name"-property -
this will be null when i get the model back on Post.

Do i have to include Name as one of the properties and user a Hiddenfor-field or is there a better way; to only update the fields that are declared in the ViewModel class?

Comment: If you dont need the property and especially if you dont want it modified then it should be excluded from the ViewModel and not put in a hiddenfield since this can be tampered with on the Post request. Most of the mapping tools like Automapper should be able to handle this, but you will need to manually handle this on the server if not.

Comment: First of all, thanks for all your help. Now a few last questions:

- Let's say i have two viewmodels for the same domain object:
Vm1 and Vm2. Can I use the same post method to save them?
If so; how - How would the method be declared?
Should i have a ViewModelBase that Vm1 and Vm2 inherit from and go:
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModelBase model)
{...}

Comment: - When i save them, i need to fetch the domain object from the repository, update the properties on the domain object that exist in the current View Model. And then save the domain object back to repository.
Is there a smooth way of doing this, or should i "manually" copy each property?
Should the viewmodel have knowledge of doing this?